# Remove a URL search parameter when there is duplicate names?

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am trying to manipulate my URL using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).  However `URLSearchParams.delete()` expects the name of the param.  If I have params with the same name, (from what I've tested in chrome) It will delete all params with that name.  Is there a way to delete by both name and value?

My query looks something like this:

`?color[]=Black&color[]=Green&material[]=Steel`

So when I call `.delete("color[]")` it will remove both `color[]=` params, but what if I want to only remove a specific one?

The reason for the duplicate names is the backend (PHP) is leveraging [this functionallity](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to auto parse the parameters into arrays...which requires the syntax above.

Big picture is- I'm trying to add/remove "filters" from this array-to-be. Also, some filter categories could have matching values so I don't want remove by value either.  I am open to considering an entirely new approach...just trying to do it in the least hacky way.

#### -- Edit --

For any Laravel users, I recommend not using the index-less syntax.  Just use `color[0]=`, `color[1]=` etc.  I didn't realize laravel supports both syntaxes.

Comment: What do you mean "`delete()` expects the name of the param"? Where does the `delete()` function come from?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @code it is a method of the URLSearchParams interface

Comment: *Is there a way to delete by both name and value*  *I don't want remove by value either* , rather confusing

Comment: A test https://jsfiddle.net/9h82gjwx/ run on Firefox shows, that `delete()` removes all parameters of the name (just as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete)). Can you provide code (and environment, e.i. browser), that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RoToRa You are correct, I didn't test correctly -- updated

Comment: Just parse the query string manually. Split on &, then loop through splitting again on =.

Comment: @ProGu I want to delete by a unique key/value pair.  Neither the key or the value are unique enough to identify the specific parameter.  (similar concept to a composite key in SQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a specific key/value pair, loop over the entries, filter out the unwanted one(s) and create a new `URLSearchParams`:

```
function deleteParamsEntry(params, key, value) {
    const newEntries = Array.from(params.entries()).filter(
      ([k, v]) => !(k === key && v === value)
    );
   return new URLSearchParams(newEntries);
}

const query = "?color[]=Black&color[]=Green&material[]=Steel";
const params = new URLSearchParams(query);

const newParams = deleteParamsEntry(params, "color[]", "Green");

console.log(newParams.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
const deleteURLParamsByNameAndValue = (urlString, paramName, paramValue) => {
  const url = new URL(urlString)
  const params = url.searchParams
  const newParamArray = []
  for (var kvPair of params.entries()) {
    const k = kvPair[0]
    const v = kvPair[1]
    if (k!==paramName || v!==paramValue) {
      newParamArray.push(kvPair)
    }
  }
  const newSearch = new URLSearchParams(newParamArray)
  return decodeURI(`${url.origin}${url.pathname}?${newSearch}`)
}

const urlString = 'https://example.com/path1/path2?color[]=Black&color[]=Green&material[]=Steel'

deleteURLParamsByNameAndValue(urlString,'color[]','Black')
// returns 'https://example.com/path1/path2?color[]=Green&material[]=Steel'
```